# Javascript onClick within a form advice

Tags: javascript, forms, onclick

I have a line of code that reads as follows :-

```
<input type='button' name='p_send' value='Send' onClick="this.value='wait...';this.disabled=true;this.form.send_moderation.value='true';this.form.edit_Action.value='submit';this.form.onsubmit();this.form.submit();return false;">
```

Could someone explain what the onClick event handler is doing - for instance this.form.send_moderation - what would this be looking for?

Sorry for the vagueness my javascript isn't the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reference to things like:

```
this.form.send_moderation.value='true'
```

Would be referencing the form to which the button belongs 'this.form' then 'send_moderation' would be a control on that form, which you are setting the 'value' of to 'true'